# Reading data from stdin in C

Tags: c, stdin

I'm trying to read from `stdin` and output the data, things work, EXCEPT that it's not outputting the *new incoming data*. I'm not quite sure where is the issue. I'm guessing it has something to do when determining the `stdin` size. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
tail -f file | my_prog
```

### Updated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

long size(FILE *st_in) {
    struct stat st;
    if (fstat(fileno(st_in), &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;
    return -1;
}

int main (){
   FILE *file = stdin;
   char line [ 128 ];  

   while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL )
      fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */

   long s1, s2; 
   s1 = size(file);
   for (;;) {
      s2 = size (file);
      if (s2 != s1) {
         if (!fseek (file, s1, SEEK_SET)) {
            while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) { 
               fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
            }   
         }   
         s1 = s2; 
         usleep(300000);
      }   
   }   
   return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

After a `FILE *` has reached EOF, it stays in a state where it will read no more data until you clear the 'EOF' bit either with [`clearerr()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clearerr.html) or with `fseek()`.  However, if standard input is connected to a terminal, then that is not a seekable device, so instead of clearing the error, it might not do anything useful:

[POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html) says:

> The behavior of fseek() on devices which are incapable of seeking is implementation-defined.

Your loop entry condition is suspect; you need to sleep before starting it, and you need to sleep on each iteration.  Indeed, normally you write `tail -f` without worrying about the file size; you sleep, try to read until the next 'EOF', reset the file EOF indicator, and repeat.  Note, too, that the size of a pipe or terminal is not defined.

---

Separately, it is aconventional to call a `FILE *` argument to a function `filename`; it has completely the wrong connotations.  A filename is a string.

Comment: `the size of a pipe or terminal is not defined.` does that mean that I can't reliably keep streaming by doing `fstat` on `stdin`?

Comment: Actually it does work. For some reason inputting new lines into the file from vim it wont update, however, it works by doing `cat >> file` Thanks

Comment: @MikeCooper: regarding 'size': you can't reliably use size on stdin if stdin is coming from a pipe or a terminal.  You might get sane answers on your system; you won't on every system.

Comment: @MikeCooper: If your code is reading from a file, it will work adequately; if your code is reading from a pipe or a terminal, it may or may not work sanely.  If you overwrite the file with vim, you may or may not get the result you expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really standard C:

```
size(file);
```

Call stat() to get file information - organization type of a file, file size and permissions.

What your code does is to eventually set the file pointer to the end of the file,  as it tries to read through it.  Consider stat() (or fstat() on a an open file) instead.

rewind() resets the file pointer to the start of the file, fseek() will place it anywhere you need.

tail -f repeatedly tries the file at the EOF point with a short sleep in between tries....  It does not "consider" EOF to be an error.  It remembers the current file offset for the EOF, then fseeks() using  SEEK_END, then calls ftell(), and compares the offsets.  If there is a difference it then fseek()-s back to the last known  endpoint and reads the data.

This description is from old unix source.  I'm sure it has been tweaked since then.

Comment: Actually `size();` is a function that it's implemented above `main()`.

Comment: Yup it sure is. But use stat() anyway.  Suppose the file is 150GB. It can take several minutes to do the I/O to get to the end of the file. Note: I edited my post.  stat() -ftell() and fseek() are much more useful for a tail -f application than is any sequentuial read operation.

Comment: fseek uses the OS to position the file pointer, forcing the kernel to skip over intervening file data.

Comment: Does `stat` accepts `stdin` as input? or do I need to convert it from `FILE` to a int file descriptor?

Comment: `stat()` will work on stdin, provided it is connected to a disk file.

Comment: so you are saying `if (stat(file, &st) == 0) return st.st_size;` where `file` is `FILE *file = stdin`?

Comment: @wallyk: No it won't, `stat` takes a filename.  You can use `fstat` on file descriptor 0 (or equivalently `fileno(stdin)`), which will work when stdin is a disk file, but not when it is a terminal or a pipe.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was careless.  I assumed we were talking `fstat()`, despite what my fingers did.